# Access the Camera and CameraRoll on Android using React Native?

Tags: android, ios, camera, reactjs, react-native

I would like to build an app in React Native were I can access the Camera and CameraRoll.

I have found that for iOS there is something implemented: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html but its not supported on android. Also access to the camera is supported on iOS thru a third party library: https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera but the same thing, android is not supported.

With so many basic  things lacking how can someone build an native app using react native?

Comment: Hello, I have posted a new question regarding on the subject, any help would be appreciated:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436262/working-example-for-android-react-native-image-picker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-image-picker with pretty good results thus far

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the [CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html#savetocameraroll) API does support Android now.